# ¿ Cómo mantener el valor seleccionado de un select

Tags: java, html, web

Mi duda es como mantener el valor de un `select` después de hacer un `submit`, ya que siempre me regresa al primer valor de la lista.

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto web con `jsp`, el `select` es llenado desde la base de datos, y funciona bien solo quiero que después de dar `submit` quede en la opción que ya se selecciono.

```
ResultSet rs = null;
            try {
                Conexion cn = new Conexion();
         rs = cn.getselectPromotor();
         ResultSetMetaData rs2 = rs.getMetaData();
                //creado un lista con los nombre de los promotores que estan en la BD
                out.println("<form name='form1' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>");
                out.println("Promotor :");
                out.println("<select name='listPromotor' id='listPromotor'>");

                while (rs.next()) {
                    String arreglo1 = (String) rs.getString("idPromotor");
                    String arreglo2 = (String) rs.getString("Nombre");

                    //llenando la lista desplegable, en el value se almacena el id y se muestra solo el nombre
                    out.println("<option value=" + arreglo1 + ">" + arreglo2 + "</option>");

                }
                out.println("</select>");
                out.println("<input type='submit' value='Buscar' name='Buscar' />");
                out.println("</form>");
```

al dar buscar me muestra los registros pero vuelve al primer valor de la tabla de la BD

Comment: ¿Podría proporcionar el código que tienes hasta el momento, por favor? Si no, es muy difícil ayudarte :)

Comment: Puedes usar [tag:ajax] para este propósito.

Comment: como se usa el ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tienes que hacer es, al principio, comprobar qué `select` está seleccionada:

```
String seleccionada = request.getParameter("listPromotor");
```

Aquí consigues el `value` de la opción seleccionada en la `select`. Ahora solo tienes que comprobar en el while que es el mismo y añadirle `selected` en la etiqueta.

```
 ResultSet rs = null;
            try {
                Conexion cn = new Conexion();
         rs = cn.getselectPromotor();
         ResultSetMetaData rs2 = rs.getMetaData();
                //creado un lista con los nombre de los promotores que estan en la BD
            out.println("<form name='form1' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>");
            out.println("Promotor :");
            out.println("<select name='listPromotor' id='listPromotor'>");

            while (rs.next()) {
                String arreglo1 = (String) rs.getString("idPromotor");
                String arreglo2 = (String) rs.getString("Nombre");



                //llenando la lista desplegable, en el value se almacena el id y se muestra solo el nombre
                if(seleccionada.equals(arreglo1)){
                out.println("<option value=" + arreglo1 + "selected>" + 
               arreglo2 + "</option>");
               }else{
                out.println("<option value=" + arreglo1 + ">" + arreglo2 + "</option>");
                  }



        }
            out.println("</select>");
            out.println("<input type='submit' value='Buscar' name='Buscar' />");
            out.println("</form>");
```

Comment: pero donde agrego la variable seleccionada?

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez no entiendo tu pregunta

Comment: String seleccionada = request.getParameter("listPromotor");  donde va?

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez Cuando pulses el submit, al método que te lleve, al principio de ese método.

Answer (score 0):

en el caso que recargues la pagina pues envialo ya sea via post o get a la direccion submit del formuario  y al recargar la pagina tomas el valor que enviaste y lo asignas.....

Comment: Hola Eder, buen día. Cuando la pregunta es muy vaga, es conveniente esperar a que se proporcione más información. Las respuestas en lo posible, no deben estar sujetas a aclaraciones del OP. Saludos y bienvenido.